# Why no article in "to cleanse what they described as (a?) deep-seated corruption"?

Tags: articles

> Months later, authorities announced a campaign to “probe backwards 20 years” into Inner Mongolia’s coal industry to cleanse what they described as deep-seated corruption.

Why isn't there an article "a" before deep-seated corruption? i.e "... what they described as *a* deep-seated corruption". I always have an issue with adding an article. I would like to correct my understanding.

Comment: Corruption is the quality of being corrupt, not a single incident.

Comment: because corruption is an abstract noun: Corruption is a terrible thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason there is no article in front of the word "corruption" is because, in this context, the word *corruption* is **uncountable**. This means that you can't have a corruption, two corruptions, and so on.

If you have trouble deciding when to use articles and when not to use them, first check if the noun is *countable* or *uncountable*.  For example, the following sentences involve countable nouns:

> I have **a** car.
>
> He ate **two** apples.
>
> She had **a** stomach ache.

Other nouns are uncountable (in certain contexts, of course):

> I have ***time***.
>
> He ate ***bread***.
>
> She had ***cancer***.

If you want to study more about countable and uncountable nouns, here are some resources for you. Good luck in your studying!

- [British Council - Countable and uncountable nouns](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-to-pre-intermediate/countable-and-uncountable-nouns-1)
- [Education First - Countable and uncountable nouns](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/countable-and-uncountable-nouns/)
- [Purdue University - Adjectives with countable and uncountable nouns](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/how_to_use_adjectives_and_adverbs/index.html)